# Check if an element is present in multiple lists in python and append it

Tags: python

I have a different columns in excel csv file, and I want to check for a condition in different columns and when condition is met, to append the found value to my new list.

But it's not working.

This is my code:

```
# importing module
from pandas import *

# reading CSV file
data = read_csv("test.csv")

# converting column data to list
ext1 = data['ext1'].tolist()
int1 = data['int1'].tolist()
ext2 = data['ext2'].tolist()

ext = []


for i in ext1 or ext2:
    if i >= "2022-03-01":
        ext.append(i)
    else:
        pass

print(*ext, sep="\n")
```

The problem is there:

`for i in ext1 or ext2:`

I think the `or` is problematic.

This is my csv file:

```
ext1,int1,ext2
2023-01-20,2022-01-20,2022-01-21
2024-01-21,2023-01-22,2024-12-22
2021-01-22,2022-01-22,2022-01-23
```

The list should print:

```
2023-01-20
2024-01-21
2024-12-22
```

it's only printing:

```
2023-01-20
2024-01-21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I fully understood the issue but try

```
for i in ext1 + ext2:
```

`ext1 or ext2` simply means *"use `ext1` if not empty, otherwise `ext2`"*.

Also get rid of `else: pass` as it is redundant.

As a side note, your whole loop can be rewritten in a single line as a list comprehension:

```
ext = [i for i in ext1 + ext2 if i >= "2022-03-01"]
```

Comment: your proposition worked, what should i replace else:pass with? Thank you!

Comment: Nothing, you don't _have to_ have an `else:` clause.